# Extend Nonce Lifetime for Specific Nonce Creation

Tags: filters, nonce

I've got as far as successfully filtering the global nonce_life but am running into trouble applying the filter in a specific function in the way described in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/278906).

```
function quote_nonce_lifetime( $day_in_seconds ) {
    return 604800; // 7 days
}
add_filter( 'nonce_life', 'quote_nonce_lifetime' );
```

The above method works and affects all nonces. However, I only want to extend the nonce lifetime for a specific kind of nonce, something like:

```
add_filter( 'nonce_life', 'quote_nonce_lifetime' );
$link = wp_nonce_url( get_site_url().'/?quote='.$id, 'view-quote' );
remove_filter( 'nonce_life', 'quote_nonce_lifetime' );
```

... but it just renders my nonce link already expired. Should this method work or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the case, but you should know that you need to add the filter both when generating the URL and upon *verifying* the nonce, i.e. the nonce lifespan needs to match in both cases. Also, you should use `add_query_arg()` to add query string to an URL..

So if you had this:

```php
add_filter( 'nonce_life', 'quote_nonce_lifetime' );

$id = 123; // just for testing
$link = wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( 'quote', $id, home_url( '/' ) ), 'view-quote' );

remove_filter( 'nonce_life', 'quote_nonce_lifetime' );
```

Then upon verifying the nonce, e.g. using `wp_verify_nonce()`, add the same filter as above:

```php
add_filter( 'nonce_life', 'quote_nonce_lifetime' );

// *In actual implementation, you should check whether the $_GET['_wpnonce'] exists.
if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['_wpnonce'], 'view-quote' ) ) {
    echo 'nonce is valid :)';
} else {
    echo 'nonce has expired!';
}

remove_filter( 'nonce_life', 'quote_nonce_lifetime' );
```

Comment: Thanks, @sally-cj – I've only just got around to implementing your suggestion this morning and am happy to say that it appears to have worked. I say "appears" because I've obviously not yet tested a link after seven days but I can tell you that they now validate, which they weren't before, as indicated in my question. Thanks again.

Comment: I believe it would work, but anyway, if you can, do let me know after the seven days have passed. :)